# How to refer to files in project directory?

Tags: python, python-os

I have some functions stored in a separate file, they access data from `csv` files. At the beggining of the script I run

```
current_dir = os.getcwd()
```

and then all the file names are in the format:

```
file_name = current_dir + '\\data\\file.csv'
```

It works well, but only if the function is called from a file that is in the project main directory, otherwise it cant find the `\data\` directory

I can set the directory to:

```
 os.chdir('D:\\Projects\\Project\\data')
```

but I would have to remember to change it manually every time I move it to new machine.

How to set the directory name so that the project is transerable to different computers / platforms and still can run and load the files from director `Project/data/` regardless where the Project it on the disk

Comment: Try to use relative paths for all your code and data files.

Comment: I'm not getting your question :/

Comment: In short I am asking how to keep track of absolute directory and only have relative paths in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you are trying to refer to some files which are in some path in your file system.

I would suggest you to place all of them in your project's root directory and refer to them using relative path as below.

```
import os
project_root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filepath = project_root_dir + name_of_the_file
#or
filepath = os.path.join(project_root_dir , name_of_the_file)
```

Or else you need to hardcode it which would cause furtherissues.

Comment: Could be -
```filepath  = os.path.join(project_root_dir , name_of_the_file)``` instead of ```filepath = project_root_dir + name_of_the_file```

Comment: Yes. That would also work. Thanks for suggestion. Adding it.